# Relation between incenter, circumcenter and orthocenter of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $\widehat{ABC}=60°$ such that $O$, $I$, $H$ are its circumcenter, incenter and orthocenter respectively. Show that $OI=IH$.

By using the laws of sines and cosines, it's rather simple to obtain that $BH=BO$, but from there I'm not sure how to proceed. It's sufficient to prove that $\widehat{OBI}=\widehat{HBI}$ in which case $BI$ would be the bisector of angle $\widehat{OBH}$ and since $OBH$ is isoceles it's also a mediator which gives us $OI=IH$. The problem is proving this angle equality...

Comment: If you already obtained $BH = BO$ then it is pretty straightforward from there. You know $\angle IBC = \angle IBA$, show outer angles are equal and that leads to $\angle OBI = \angle IBH$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Triangle ABC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFeZb.png)

Draw perpendiculars from vertex $B$ & $C$ on side $CA$ & $AB$ meeting them at points $E$ & $F$ respectively. They intersect at $H$. Draw $BO$,$OH$,$OC$ and $BI$. Extend $BI$ to meet $OH$ at $L$. Also, drop a perpendicular from the circumcentre on side $BC$ meeting it at point $M$.

Observe that, in $\triangle BOM$ & $\triangle BHF$,

$\left(i\right)$ $\angle BMO=\angle BFH=90^\text{o}$

$\left(ii\right)$ $\angle OBM=90-\frac{\angle BOC}{2}=90-\angle BAC=\angle ABE=\angle HBF$

$\left(iii\right)$ Since $\triangle BFC$ is a  $30-60-90$ triangle, $BF=\frac{1}{2}BC=BM$

Hence, $\triangle BHF\cong \triangle BOM$ by $A-S-A$ criterion of congruence.

Thus, $BO=BH$.

Since $\angle HBF=\angle OBM$ and $BI$ bisects $\angle ABC$, $BI$ must also bisect $\angle OBH$.

In $\triangle BOH$, $BI$ bisects $\angle  OBH$ and $BO=BH$; Hence, $BI$ is the perpendicular bisector of $OH$. Since $I$ lies on this perpendicular bisector, $\boxed {OI=IH}$.

Comment: +1 good solution.